# Something about ThreadGroup

Tags: java, multithreading

I try to create a class which implements Runnable.And I hope when I create a object of the class,I can also assign a threaddroup.But there is different result between the two code. Why? thanks so much.

this is codeA

```
public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {

    private String groupname;

    private boolean terminated=true;

    ThreadGroup threadGroup1=new ThreadGroup(groupname);

    ThreadDemo(String groupname){

        this.groupname=groupname;
    }
    ....
```

this is codeB

```
public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {

    private boolean terminated=true;

    ThreadGroup threadGroup1;

    ThreadDemo(String groupname){

        threadGroup1 = new ThreadGroup(groupname);
    }
    ....
```

And I create object by using codeA and codeB

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  ThreadDemo td=new ThreadDemo("group");

  Thread threadA = new Thread(td.threadGroup1,td);

  out.println(threadA.getThreadGroup().getName());

  threadA.start();

  td.terminate();

  threadA.interrupt();

}
```

the result of codeA is

> null

the console of codeB is

> group

Comment: Why? You can get the name of the thread group of the current thread any time, via `Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getName()`. You don't need any of this.

Answer (score 1):

In **codeA**, your groupname is null:

```
private String groupname; // this is null by default

private boolean terminated=true;

ThreadGroup threadGroup1=new ThreadGroup(groupname); // you pass null in here
```

In **codeB**, you pass the name of the group in the constructor:

```
ThreadGroup threadGroup1;

ThreadDemo(String groupname){

    threadGroup1 = new ThreadGroup(groupname); // gets the name from the parameter
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because the attribute is built earlier than construtor, so if you

```
private String groupname;

private boolean terminated=true;

ThreadGroup threadGroup1=new ThreadGroup(groupname);

ThreadDemo(String groupname){

    this.groupname=groupname;
```

you will get null sine attribute "String groupname"is null before creating

ThreadGroup threadGroup1=new ThreadGroup(groupname);

Comment: I see!!Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

In **codeA** you are passing thread-group name as **null** to ThreadGroup

Refer below link, it will clear your thoughts/ doubts about object initialization

[Initialization blocks, constructors and their order of execution](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/initialization-blocks-constructors-and-their-order-of-execution/)